# Why do sections and gradients not display properly on mobile (iOS)?

Tags: css

I am attempting to create three sections:

1. a `<header>` with a fixed gradient background,
2. a `<section>` with a solid background, and
3. a `<section>` with a different gradient background.

They all share the properties `min-height: 100vh` and `max-width: 100vw`, so each takes up the entire screen on scroll.

[CodePen here.](https://codepen.io/mattmc318/pen/QWWmqRm)

I expect it to behave on mobile like it does on desktop: three sections that take up the whole screen on scroll, two of which have fixed background gradients. Instead, on mobile I see only the header with no way to scroll, and the gradient is stretched out beyond the confines of the viewport.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a support problem:

[HTML5 Semantic Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic)

[Viewport Units Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Try using simple `div` blocks or using `%` units in css.

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested [here](https://codepen.io/mattmc318/pen/zYYWpdz), along with some jQuery to adjust the `div` height based on window height. The code has similar issues, however. It works on desktop, but all I see on mobile is a solid `rgb(204, 101, 252)` (the last of the first gradient's colors) background that doesn't scroll.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a iOS device to do a complete debug of the problem. You can try to replace gradients with flat colors, or insert something in the divs, or replace units with absolute ones (px). You can also try to use a different browser on the same device.

Comment: So far, I've replaced gradients with solid colors, added `h1` elements to the divs, and used absolute units when resizing in jQuery. The issue appears to have nothing to do with the gradients, or compatibility issues as suggested. Rather, I had trouble obtaining the correct value on mobile using `$(window).height()` or `document.documentElement.clientHeight`. On mobile, I expected the value to be somewhere around 300px or 400px, but the value I obtained was 33554432. I suspect that finding the size of an `iframe` on mobile is what caused the issue.

Comment: The result was the same in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox on iOS 12.4.2. Link to updated CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/mattmc318/pen/qBBYbeK).

Comment: Try adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the `head` section of your page.

Comment: That is already in my project code, and adding it to the CodePen did nothing.

Comment: On android mobile device with chrome browser all works perfectly.

Comment: That's good to know, since I don't have my own Android device at the moment. I seem to run into more issues with Apple every year.

Comment: Your help is appreciated.